# /gvsf empty, gvsf-fuse not working (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: gvfs, smb

In my work U usually have to manage a lot of files through SMB / shared folders, sometimes I use Uget to download files directly to server. Uget does not support smb, so I use `/gvfs` virtual folder to make it work.

Recentlly gvfs became empty and I faced serious problems sending files directly from uget to the server. After a lot of search I learnt that gvsf-fuse is the daemon responsible for the gvfs virtual folder, then I found out the following problems:

1. `/gvfs` with wrong permissions
2. `gvfs-fuse` not working

gvfs will only work if I dismount and run gvfs-fuse again

```
sudo umount -l /run/user/1000/gvfs
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -o big_writes
```

After restarting gvfs-fuse will stop working again.

By default system starts gvfs-fuse as

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
```

If I use this command in some terminal, it will stop working and never end processing.

Can anyone help me to leave gvfs-fuse functioning normally as before?

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` option means "Run in the foreground" according to the man page.  The command will work whether or not I have the `-f` switch (you can use another terminal to list the `/run/user/1000/gvfs` directory).

I am having the same problem.  I am not sure why it stopped working.  I am thinking this may be caused by a bug [described here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753561).  Since I can work around by unmounting and running gvfsd-fuse again, I'm going to let it be for now.  Those commands can be made to run automatically on boot.

Comment: Perhaps a "temporary" solution is to create a script with the following lines:

`pkill gvfsd-fuse
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -o big_writes`

start it on every login.